# How to open port 7011 on Samsung Orsay Smart TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I've been developing on Samsung Smart TV for years and I've recently had to modify a project for Orsay (ie pre-Tizen) devices.  Remote Web Inspector is normally available for debugging on port 7011 but after being unable to connect to the debugger, I ran an nmap scan and it seems the port is now closed.

A couple of others have reported the same issue on the Samsung Developer Forums and 1:1 QA no longer offer tech support on pre-2014 devices.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and how did they solve it?

Comment: I also, have the same issue. Have you found the solution yet?